# Not able to add webpart to page using chrome

Tags: 2007, development, visual-web-part

I created a visual webpart for SharePoint 2007, now I am able to add it to page using Internet Explorer but when I try to add it to page using chrome it doesn't add it or do a page refresh, I followed this tutorial

[How to build visual WebPart in SharePoint 2007](http://vimeo.com/11285888)

**EDIT**

Actually I am not able to add any webpart to page using Chrome and it was working before until what time I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Ben said, Chrome and SharePoint 2007 do not play nicely together.  There is an extension for Chrome called IE Tab

[Chrome Extension for using IE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd)

It will render the page using the IE engine while still in Chrome.  You can configure it to use the IE Tab automatically by URL.

Comment: TechNet Library lists the browsers supported in SP 2007. Chrome is not one of them. (ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint and Chrome really don't play nice.  FF is better but still has oddities.  Leave your soul at the door and use the latest version of IE.

I feel dirty saying that.